# View inside each with itemController

Tags: ember.js

I've created view `App.TestView` which works fine outside following each loop. The code is displaying properly `test loop_element`.

```
App.TestView = Ember.View.extend({});

{{#view App.TestView}}
test
{{/view}}
{{#each controller.positions itemController='url'}}
 loop_element
{{/each}}
```

On the other hand, when I put child view inside each loop

```
{{#each controller.positions itemController='url'}}
    loop_element

    {{#view App.TestView}}
    test
    {{/view}}
{{/each}}
```

is not displaying anything. There isn't any error message. What can be wrong? Why can't I use views inside loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's working to me.  Are you sure you're looping the same thing?  You wrote two different items that you were iterating.  `controller.positions` is probably empty

```
App.TestView = Em.View.extend({

});

App.UrlController = Em.ObjectController.extend({

});


<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{#each controller.positions itemController='url'}}
      loop_element

      {{#view App.TestView}}
      test2

      {{/view}}
    {{/each}}
  </script>
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bapugowi/1/edit

Comment: `Controller.positions` is not empty. It is displaying everything fine unless I put inside my view. The behaviour is strange and I can't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

The thing was that the loop was inside `<tbody>` tag. View was rendered in other tag than `<tr>` and it was breaking my web browser.

Comment: http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/03/30/ember-1-5-0-and-ember-1-6-beta-released.html Glad you found it!